# Linq: Selecting current month Data but checking if anything needs carrying over from previous months

Tags: c#, linq

I currently have this linq:

```
var filterdForecastRevenue = filteredWonSales
    .Where(x => x.ProjectStartDate.Month.Equals(month.Month) 
                && x.ProjectStartDate.Year.Equals(month.Year));

foreach (var rev in filterdForecastRevenue)
{   
    if (rev.ProjectDurationMonths > 0)
    {
        rev.ForecastSell = rev.ForecastSell / rev.ProjectDurationMonths;
    }
}

var forecastRevenueTotal = (filterdForecastRevenue.Any()) 
                              ? filterdForecastRevenue.Sum(x => x.ForecastSell) : 0;
```

My Class:

```
public class WonSaleView
{
    [Key]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Jobnumber { get; set; }
    public double ForecastSell { get; set; }
    public DateTime ProjectStartDate { get; set; }
    public int ProjectDurationMonths { get; set; }
}
```

This works, but what i need is:
Values need to carry over from previous months i.e. If `ProjectStartDate` Is in July but runs for 3 months (`ProjectDurationMonths`) i need to carry over the calculate `ForecastSell` in August and September as well.

I tried for 3 hours trying to figure out such a simple task, any help is fantastic.

Comment: Can you show the class(es) you are using

Comment: Hi @PeterSmith, i have added the class, thank you.

Comment: You want to show 3 months records? Right?

Comment: carry over means you want that 3 months `ForecastSell` as yout total?

Comment: @CoolJK, it needs to be calculated for the 3 months for this instance yes, but each  entry might have a different number of `ProjectDurationMonths`

Comment: Instead of filtering on current month why not just get total for each month that remains and sum that if necessary. You now the project start date and duration.

Answer (score 0):

You are converting a DateTime to intergers (month, year).  It is better to use the DateTime Object. See code below :

```
DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
DateTime firstOfMonth = new DateTime(now.Year, now.Month, 1);

var filterdForecastRevenue = filteredWonSales
    .Where(x => (x.ProjectStartDate >= firstOfMonth) 
|| ((x.ProjectStartDate.AddMonths(rev.ProjectDurationMonths) >= firstOfMonth));
```

Answer (score 0):

If understand correctly you need project which are "active" during given month.
Quickly can come up only with two queries

```
var now = DateTime.Now();
var startMonth = new DateTime(now.Year, now.Month, 1);
var endMonth = startMonth.AddMonths(1).AddSeconds(-1);

var fullyOverlaping = 
   filteredWonSales.Where(sale => sale.ProjectStartDate < startMonth)
                   .Where(sale => sale.ProjectStartDate.AddMonths(rev.ProjectDurationMonths) > endMonth);

var withinMonth = 
   filteredWonSales.Where(sale => (sale.ProjectStartDate >= startMonth && sale.ProjectStartDate <= endMonth) ||
                         (sale.ProjectStartDate.AddMonths(rev.ProjectDurationMonths) >= startMonth && sale.ProjectStartDate.AddMonths(rev.ProjectDurationMonths) <= endMonth));

var all = withinMonth.Concat(fullyOverlaping);
```

Comment: You just copied my code and may changes that I'm not sure are necessary.